# Starting Node.js server from code

Tags: node.js

Is there anyway to start Node.js server from code? I mean a way other than opening the command prompt and typing node SomeFile.js?

Comment: You can spawn a child process from code

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin and? my problem is in starting the server from code

Comment: "which code"? If from node.js, then you already have running instance.

Comment: no, I mean, I have some node.js code that I need to launch and take its output using another application, like android application, that's why I'm asking for any way other than command line.

Comment: When you spawn a child process you can read it's input. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear, what I want is something to run node.js code from android studio

Comment: Thing is your android app can not directly start your node server as both are in different platform, but yes if you have a server running (J2EE or Node or PHP), your app can invoke a function via an API and your server can run the node server process. Like in nodejs server it can execute a new process. But again it will run the command `node app.js`